# how to install TYPO3 NEOS on openshift

Tags: composer-php, redhat, openshift, typo3-flow, neoscms

Unable to install typo3 neos on openshift.

my git repository https://github.com/ynagarjuna1995/neos

but when I execute rhc create app appname php-5.3 mysql-5.1 --from-code=https://github.com/ynagarjuna1995/neos

it has initialized the gear .but no result .

Please make repository of Typo3 Neos to install on Openshift

Comment: It seems like this should be posted on [the Typo3 NEOS issue tracker](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/package-typo3-neos/issues?set_filter=1) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try TYPO3 Neos on OpenShift too (and then share my expirience of course), but haven't done it yet.

Any particular reason you try this with (almost deprecated) PHP 5.3? Have you tried PHP 5.4/5.5? Neos works perfectly on PHP 5.5.

Comment: I have tried php 5.4 on openshift.

Installed Neos on Openshift in the app-root/runtime/repo/php  with the composer
But the problem I was able to see TYPO3 Favicon But unable to see installation
Please share the REPO If you install on openshift and Setting to be changed for the normal usage in README File

Comment: Both of you let me know if you hit some walls. I have no idea about OpenShift and no account, but am willing to help to get it running.

Comment: http://clickntoor-arcmagnus.rhcloud.com/  by Openshift Link 
TYPO3 Favoicon is visible but unable to through actual installtion procedure